# "Run script section if condition satisfied" in R

Tags: r

I'm currently using R to run MCMCglmm and have a long section of script (many lines) which take an fairly large amount of time (~5 days) to run. I saved the output and reload it now while having set the entire section in to comments (by putting # at the start of each line), but in the future I will need to tweak some things and rerun the chains. Currently if I want to do that I have to go and remove all those  #'s, run the script, and replace them when the chains are done. Is there a function I could wrap my occasionally used script in to to switch that bit of code on or off? a bit like this:

```
run_chains = "yes" # type yes or no
run_script(if run_chains = "yes", run the following section of code:
chain = MCMCglmm ....
.... MCMCglmm code ....
.... more MCMCglmm code ....
, else ignore this section of code)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if(run_chains=="yes") { <code> } else { <more code> }` ?

Comment: The only thing wrong with that is I didn't think of it! I'll try it and let you know it works, write it up as an answer and I can accept it if it does :) @JoshuaUlrich (I'm self taught on R so miss quite a few of these sorts of tricks!)

Comment: If it doesn't work then you should provide a (non)-working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JoshuaUlrich posted the solution as a comment - the key was `if(){}else(){}`

```
run = "yes"
if(run=="yes"){
print("A")
}else{
print("B")
}

> run = "yes"
> if(run=="yes"){
+ print("A")
+ }else{
+ print("B")
+ }
[1] "A"
> 
> run = "no"
> if(run=="yes"){
+ print("A")
+ }else{
+ print("B")
+ }
[1] "B"
>
```

Note that `else{}` can be left empty to perform no action.